# Boot folder is almost full, how to give it more space?

Tags: disk-usage, boot-partition

My boot folder or whatever it is dev/sda1/boot only has about 300mb of memory and it's about full. I'm not sure why it has so little memory. I have a toshiba laptop and removed the windows and installed ubuntu with a flashdrive. Is there a way I can move memory to the boot folder so it has plenty of room for future updates etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would first go to it and try to free up some space, if that doesnt fix it try to boot into live USB and resize the partition, note you should be careful not to damage all others.